# __methodptr in decompiled C# code

Tags: c#, delegates, decompiling

I'm using dotPeek to dive deeper into the C# compiler magic, and something in decompiled code caught my attention. I'm creating an `Action<int>` instance and pass it to `Start()` method, the compiler generates the following:

```
new Program().Start(new Action<int>((object) cDisplayClass1, __methodptr(<Main>b__0)));
```

I generally understand what's happening here, my only question is what is __methodptr? To be exact, where does it come from? Is it from IL? dotPeek doesn't know a thing about it or the assembly containing it. Google doesn't give a precise answer either, only the same snippets of code with no explanations whatsoever.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a bug in the decompiler.  Was the assembly compiled by Roslyn?

Comment: Anybody who *thinks* they need an obfuscator did not write enough anonymous delegates, iterators, lambda expressions, Linq and async methods.  The kind of code that is pretty impervious to decompilation.  Afaik, dotPeek usually also emits an `// ISSUE: method pointer` comment to warn you that it gave up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the **__methodptr** corresponds to IL instruction **ldftn**, roughly speaking  **ldftn** load "function pointer" onto evaluation stack. here is a sample:

**the de-compiled source:**

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0_0 cDisplayClass00 = new Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass0_0();
      cDisplayClass00.xx = 100;
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      new Action((object) cDisplayClass00, __methodptr(\u003CMain\u003Eb__0))();
      Console.WriteLine(cDisplayClass00.xx);
    }
```

**the IL:**

1 load function pointer class::method

```
IL_000f: ldloc.0      // cDisplayClass00
IL_0010: ldftn        instance void TestIL.Program/'<>c__DisplayClass0_0'::'<Main>b__0'()
```

2 new a delegate passing object and function pointer

```
IL_0016: newobj       instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_001b: stloc.1      // V_1
```

3 call the delegate

```
IL_001c: ldloc.1      // V_1
IL_001d: callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::Invoke()
IL_0022: nop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace code as follows :

new Action(cDisplayClass00.Mainb__0))();

So to speak, function pointer to auto generated method on auto generated class.